# mmap: map a ARM linux kernel for emulation

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, emulation, qemu

I need to map a ARM linux Kernel (I have only the binary) into the memory space of a qemu arm linux OS, because I need to emulate the behaviour of some function embedded into the kernel.
I already succeeded in mapping and emulating the bootloader (mapped at 0x20008000) of the kernel, but as I do mmap for the linux kernel, I got an error "Cannot allocate memory". I think this is because I'm trying to map the kernel binary into the same address space of the running kernel.
The address I want to map the kernel to is 0xC0008000.

This is the mmap function call I wrote:

`map_result = mmap(0xC0008000, buffer_length, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);`

fd is the file descriptor with the linux kernel binary.

I also tried with `MAP_SHARED` but I get the same error.

Is there a way to force the mapping?

Thank you

Comment: Processes can only mmap to addresses below the "VM split" address that marks the boundary between user address space (below the VM split address) and kernel address space (above the VM split address). 0xC0008000 is above the VM split address (on a 32-bit system).

Comment: "In to the memory space of a qemu arm linux OS" is confusing. Are you trying to make this binary visible to the guest OS (in the emulated system address space) or to QEMU (in the QEMU process's addres space)? Are you trying to make changes to QEMU, or is this some other program doing the mmap()?

Comment: @PeterMaydell I need to emulate some functions of a ARM Linux kernel I extracted from a device. So I'm using the Azeria Lav VM 2.0 (https://azeria-labs.com/lab-vm-2-0/). I wrote a C code that maps the kernel I want to emulate into the VM memory, declare a function pointer to the function I want to emulate and then I call it. This procedure worked for the U-Boot used to load the linux kernel, but not with the kernel. I Think the reason in the one explained by Ian, because the U-Boot starts at 20008000 while the kernel starts at c0008000

Comment: @IanAbbott, is there a way to find the split address?

Comment: The VM split address is set by the "Memory split" sub-menu in the kernel configuration menu, which sets one of the options `CONFIG_VMSPLIT_3G` (3G/1G user/kernel split with user addresses up to 0xC0000000), `CONFIG_VMSPLIT_3G_OPT` (3G/1G user/kernel split for full 1G low memory with user addresses up to 0xC0000000), `CONFIG_VMSPLIT_2G` (2G/2G user/kernel split with user addresses up to 0x80000000), or `CONFIG_VMSPLIT_1G (1G/3G user/kernel split with user addresses up to 0x40000000).